# my app is facing this error Unable to install the application Installation failed

Tags: android, game-development, chrome-app-developer-tool

**application Installation failed**..

my app is facing this error Unable to install the application Installation failed..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WPRw.jpg
i am a game developer my application is getting rejected by galaxy store. although the application is working fine in my device

( Unable to install the application Installation failed...(-124)Tested on S20+).. this was the statement given by them

Comment: probably, you do not have enough spaces for installation.

Comment: try clear galaxy store app data using setting and restart then try again.